# Qual a classe gramatical do "que" nessa frase?

Tags: sintaxe

Qual a classe gramatical do "que" na frase abaixo?

> Esse é um setor que tem transformado milhares de vidas nos últimos anos, fazendo com **que** muitas pessoas consigam vencer os problemas financeiros

Answer (score 1):

É um complementador (tradicionalmente chamado de [*conjunção integrante*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/que)). Introduz uma oração completiva oblíqua.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja "conjunção final". Segundo o dicionário Priberam "Usa-se para introduzir intenção ou finalidade em relação ao que foi dito anteriormente"

"que", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://dicionario.priberam.org/que [consultado em 12-02-2019].

Entendo que "fazendo com que muitas pessoas consigam vencer os problemas financeiros" mostre a finalidade em relação ao que foi dito anteriormente.

Comment: Verena, repara que no Priberam, logo a seguir à frase que tu citas, diz que a conjunção final *que* é equivalente a *a fim de que*. Ora, não podes substituir "fazendo com **que**" por "fazendo com **a fim de que**". O exemplo do Priberam é "tomai atenção que não caiais em tentação" (aqui já podes por *a fim de que*), e o *que* mostra a finalidade de "tomai atenção". Mas na frase da pergunta--"fazendo com que..."--o *que* não indica a finalidade de "fazendo com"; antes introduz uma oração que completa o sentido de "fazendo com" ; ou seja é conjunção integrante (9 no Priberam) >>

Comment: Compara com o exemplo do Priberam: "digo que tem razão"; "que tem razão" completa o sentido de "digo", tal como "com que as pessoas consigam..." completa o sentido de "fazendo".